# How can we measure data transmission rate in Arduino for nrf24l01 module?

Tags: c++, arduino, radio-transmission

These Arduino codes developed for nRF24L01 module. It's an RF module which provides wireless communication between 2 points. And my purpose is to measure the data transmission rate between these 2 points.

This is the example of transmitter code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}
void loop() {
  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));      
}
```

This code basically sending a string which is "Hello World" over the channel. First I'm calling some libraries related with module. Than I'm defining the pin numbers that module uses. Than I'm naming the module. After that some properties such as listening mode and power level of the module set. And finally message send over the loop. Also receiver code is provided below:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7,8);

const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {


  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0,address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {

  if (radio.available()){

    char text[32] = "";
    radio.read(&text,sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);

  }

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Receiver logic is same as the transmitter.

All in all, the question is how can we measure the data rate as bit per second for this wireless communication?

Answer (score 1):

Measuring bit rate between two devices/computers is tricky as you either need to have synchronised clocks, or else measure round trip and either measure or estimate the turn around time on the node doing the 'reflection'.

If you can set up a network sniffer or make the measurements on a router then you may find it easier to get some figures.

As an example, with WireShark (https://www.wireshark.org) you can see throughout information in "Statistics" -> "End Points" ands then the IPV4 or IPV6 tab should show all the traffic between the devices, or more accurately between these IP interfaces as devices may have more than one port. Other tools include nTop (https://www.ntop.org/products/netflow/nprobe/). Router vendors also generally include tools to measure this type of information - for example the TTCP utility (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ttcp) is usually available on Cisco equipment.

Its also worth noting that a measurement of bit rate only tells you what it was when you measured it not what it will be when you next try as so many factors, including network traffic, load on the nodes etc can influence it.

Answer (score 1):

The major variable is whether you are using 1mb/s or 2mb/s.  You can get close by using the formula on pages 38 and 39 of the NRF24L01 v2 spec, however, the best way to measure it is to enable auto-ack.  As mentioned my Mick, if you can't synchronize the two clocks (Tx and Rx devices), the best you can do is use the auto ack to have the Rx send data back.  Since the switch over time is fixed at 130us and the time for the IRQ is either 6ns or 8ns, you can set a pin high just before you send the message and pull it low once you get the ACK IRQ.  This will give you the time it took to send, and ack (again with the additional 130us to have each device change roles).